# Windows Phone 7 ASX Streaming

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying a small app which play a asx streaming file. My understanding was i should parse the asx and get the URL. But in my case, REFHREF in ASX points like this www.website.com:8084. Is this the server configuration need to be modified ? Totally new to this audio streaming protocols. Any suggestion would be much appreacited ...
My code streams audio fine when i test with a ww.website.com/file.MP3

Comment: I tried HTTP, MMS in URL of my code and no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the URL from refhref may most probably lead you to another asx file, which needs to be parsed again, i would advice recursively parsing till u reach a valid playable stream! Wp7 supports asx streams but it disallows(throws an exception for some tags check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) )

so you will have to parse the asx yourself, extract the URL and process it further!

Good Luck! post your findings too!